# Threaded output not displayed when run from command (works from irb)

Tags: ruby, multithreading, net-ssh

I decided to rewrite a ruby script I did as a gem/module with an executable component.  The original works fine, but as a gem it is easier to maintain/install with all dependencies.

The command takes an array of hosts and a command, and runs it on the hosts via threads.  The problem I am now having though is that the output of the command is not displayed on the terminal.  Executing the module code from within IRB however produces the output.

The module code is as follows:

```
require "rcmd/version"
require 'net/ssh'
require 'thread'
module Rcmd
  @queue = Queue.new
  class << self
    attr_accessor :nthreads
    attr_accessor :user
    attr_accessor :quiet
    attr_accessor :command
    attr_accessor :host_list
    attr_accessor :threads
  end
  # Built in function called by each thread for executing the command on individual hosts
  def Rcmd.run_command_on_host(conn_options)
    begin
      # Create ssh session to host
      Net::SSH.start(conn_options[:host], conn_options[:user], :password => conn_options[:passwd]) do |session|
        # Open channel for input/output control
        session.open_channel do |channel|
          channel.on_data do |ch, data|
            # Print recieved data if quiet is not true
            puts "#{conn_options[:host]} :: #{data}" unless conn_options[:quiet]
          end
          channel.on_extended_data do |ch,type,data|
            # Always print stderr data
            puts "#{conn_options[:host]} :: ERROR :: #{data}"
          end
          # Execute command
          channel.exec @command
        end
        # Loop until command completes
        session.loop
    end
    rescue
      puts "#{conn_options[:host]} :: CONNECT ERROR :: Unable to connect to host!\n"
    end
  end
  # Main method of module for starting the execution of the specified command on provided hosts
  def Rcmd.run_command()
    if not @command
      raise ArgumentError.new("No command set for execution")
    end
    if not @host_list.count >= 1
      raise ArgumentError.new("host_list must contain at least one system")
    end
    @host_list.each do |host|
      @queue << host
    end
    until @queue.empty?
      # Don't start more threads then hosts.
      num_threads = @nthreads <= @host_list.count ? @nthreads : @host_list.count
      # Prepare threads
      @threads = { }
      num_threads.times do |i|
        @threads[i] = Thread.new {
          conn_options = { :user => @user, :host => @queue.pop, :password => nil, :quiet => @quiet}
          unless conn_options[:host].nil?
            self.run_command_on_host(conn_options)
          end
        }
      end
      # Execute threads
      @threads.each(&:join)
    end
  end
end
```

Test snippet:

```
require 'rcmd'
Rcmd.host_list= ["localhost", "dummy-host"]
Rcmd.nthreads= 2
Rcmd.user= 'root'
Rcmd.command= "hostname -f"
Rcmd.run_command
```

Running the above in IRB produces:

```
dummy-host :: CONNECT ERROR :: Unable to connect to host!
localhost :: darkstar.lan
```

As expected.  However, Running the same from a script file (the gem command) or in ruby directly results in no output:

```
ruby-newb@darkstar:~/repos/rcmd$ rcmd -n localhost,dummy-host -c 'hostname -f'
ruby-newb@darkstar:~/repos/rcmd$
```

Previously I used $stdout.puts and $stderr.puts as well as the constants variants but in desperation moved it to just puts.  I have also tried with print and various other ways to include handing the streams to the threads and printing all output once the thread finished , but to no avail.

After adding tons of 'p' statements through out the code, when running from the command the output stops just before the Net::SSH.start call in the run_command_on_host method.

I have also tried having that entire method within the thread creations but then it failed to execute completely.  Hence having two methods. One for creating the threads, and one used by the threads for executing the ssh session and command.

Failing in both ruby-2.3.3 and ruby-2.0.0-p648 so I think I am just doing something stupid.

If someone could find it in their hearts to tell this Ruby newbie where he has gone wrong it would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure exactly why but it seems the method call was exiting (not waiting on the threads despite the thread joins) and thus killing the threads.  As such, the Net::SSH module did not have time to get/return data.

I added the following unless statement near the end of the code to force the method to wait for the threads to complete and now output is displayed as desired.  Also reduced the amount of code a bit.

```
unless @threads.each.map {|t| t.alive?}.none?
    sleep 1
end
```